# "Missing { inserted" keeps popping up in my code

Tags: latex

For line 14,17 it keep saying "Missing { inserted" but I don't know what does that mean.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \title{}
 \author{}
 \date{February 03 2019}

 \begin{document}

 \maketitle

 \section{Problem 1.11}

 Assume $a$ is irrational and $a^\sqrt{3}$ is rational.\newline
 Let's say $a = \sqrt[3]{x}$ and $x$ is a rational number.\newline
 If we square $a$ to $\sqrt{3}$, the result will be:\newline
 $(\sqrt[3]{x})^\sqrt{3}$ $= x$\newline
 Since $x$ is a rational number, therefore ,the proof is completed.

 \section{Problem 3.18}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some brackets when raising your variables to an exponent.
For example:

`$a^\sqrt{3}$`

needs to be

`$a^{\sqrt{3}}$`